# How to safely handle sensitive environment variables?

Tags: shell, unix, processbuilder

I have worked on a Java app that takes a shell script as an input argument and executes it. I'm using the following block to prepare the environment:

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("/bin/bash", scriptFile);
Map<String, String> env = pb.environment();

env.putAll(environmentVariable);

Process awk = pb.inheritIO().start();
awk.waitFor();
awk.destroy();
```

In the above code block, `environmentVariable` is a Map that holds some sensitive data which would later be used by the script.

My understanding of `ProcessBuilder#environment()` is that it provides environment for only that sub-process. The changes you do to that environment affects that sub-process alone. I have verified it by going through the Javadoc of [`ProcessBuilder#environment()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html#environment--)

Now my question is, at the end of this operation i.e. when `awk.destroy()` gets called, will the environment be wiped along with all the sensitive variables that I've put or is it better to manually wipe the environment variables map with `env.remove(SENSITIVE_VARIABLE_KEY)` or `env.putAll(new HashMap<String, String>)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`process.destroy` won't clean the system env on the `ProcessBuilder`. You can still use the same PB object to start new processes, well with the same env map.

I don't understand your requirement, why you want to remove the env entry. If after your `awk` process, you don't use the `pb` object anymore, and there is no reference to it, java will garbage collect it. I don't see what brings you by removing the sensitive entries from the map. You have anyway another java variable `environmentVariable` holding your sensitive data.

For your question, if you want to remove some data, you can use `map.remove()` if you want to clean the map, you can do `pb.environment().clear()`. But if you have done this, when you start a new process with the `pb`, it will use the modified env-map.

Comment: My concern was that after my Java app exits, would it be possible to read the environment variables which my app set somehow (using any possible ways). I mean would the variables be set on the machine level so that anyone who has access to the machine can query using `printenv {VARIABLE}` or on the sub-process level?

Comment: @SivaprasannaSethuraman you've mentioned in your question that, the javadoc says the changes you made will only affect the sub-process alone. It won't be system level. You can create another ProcessBuilder after you changed env map of one PB, to test.